# wordpress themes and plugin customization

Tags: plugins

Wordpress has been the best for me.

Now I have been working with wordpress plugin and themes using various wordpress hook and filter for my site.

Currently I need to

1.) change the successful message that is display by default when a user successfully registered

2.) I need to change the various error message  during users registrations or login.  Eg email is not available, password is empty etc.

3.) I need to hide wordpresslost password link on both signup and register page

4.) I need to edit and style wordpress login form, registration form, login and signup submit button. **I already know how to change wordpress image logo**

Please what hooks or filter function do I have to call to achieve this. I cannot properly find it in wordpress codex.

Any single solution provided will be awesome. Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE. As the rules of this community goes, please ask one question per post. For example, if you have ten questions, it's better to post ten different questions instead of putting all ten questions in a single question post. That way, other users looking for the same answers will be able to find it easily. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you started here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/ ? All the hooks and filters....and more..

Or here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/ ? Hooks and stuff for plugins.

Or here (for login forms) https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form ?

Comment: The link is helpful. I was able to solve problem 1 to 3. remaining issue no 4.  Any other links on where to get info on css styling . between thanks for response so far

Comment: That last link will help you tweak the login form. It also includes, as I recall, the CSS used for the login form. But you could also figure out the CSS classes used by using the Inspector Tool (F12) in your browser. I use that all the time to make real-time tweaks to CSS classes. Once I find the settings I like, I copy that to the appropriate spot in the Child Theme's CSS files, or in Additional CSS in the theme options. Keep in mind this place is not a CSS school...but there are lots of googles/bings/ducks on that CSS stuff.

Comment: Resolved. Thanks Sir Rick